# Magento payment button disabled

Tags: magento

I'm currently just finishing a magento store to go live this afternoon,

for some reason when in the OPC and you select the payment method the continue (to the next stage) button is automatically disabled.

I have tried enabling every combination of payment methods i will be using to try and get it working again, including just using check/money order option to skip through.

it seems there is some sort of validation issue as if i set it to a manual ccsave setting and fully validate the form it will proceed.

i'll be using a paypal option for this page and have no ideas how to bypass this disabled button, i've read alot of things re: this happening in 1.4 but i'm running 1.6 and all the fixes for 1.4 are currently in place on 1.6

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you kept your modifications within your custom theme? What extensions have you installed? If you switch to default theme is OPC working normal?

Comment: i've been unable to test that as the site is currently being used. the only extensions installed re checkout are ebiz sage pay.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your checkout page is including a Javascript file called ccard.js

It should be included in the head of your HTML and look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://yourdomain.com/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
```

If that is not included, you will never be able to get the credit card form the validate (thus the button will never be disabled)

Comment: please see original post, this is for version 1.6, your solution is built into 1.6 for a 1.4 problem

Answer (score 0):

Such problems usually occur in magento when the html structure is changed and elements are moved. Open the file `template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml` and check that the button container is at the root level.

```
<!-- This should be on the root level -->
<div class="buttons-set" id="payment-buttons-container">
<!-- Buttons are here -->
</div>
```